# Open Street Maps or Google API for extracting all house locations in a City?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, openstreetmap

I am working on mapping a city like represented in the real world. So how do I map the exact locations of houses and other key buildings ?. Should I work with reverse Geocoding provided by Google or extract and manipulate raw information from OSM.

Comment: How accurate should your map be ?

Comment: You can use Overpass API to extract objects [tagged](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag) as [buildings](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:building) and similar information.

Comment: @Manuel - More accurate, the better. Let me rephrase that as accurate as it can be.

Answer (score 3):

You can't to that with the google maps geocoding API, without violating the terms of use, ragarding to chapter [10.5 Intellectual Property Restrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms), paragraph (c) and (e). This solution is very accurate but sadly there is no way to use it outside a google maps app.

The second way is to do it with OpenStreetMap. But be carefull ! OSM is a volunteered geographic map/database, with no guarantee for complete data. In a famous city there will be no problem! But if you want to get the houses in a little hamalayan village you will find no houses/data. But the simplest approach to get OSM data you may take use of the [overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). You also can use the overpass API via the  userinterface [overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/). Overpass turbo should be the approach of your choice, because there you are able to beck for existing houses/data parallel on a map.

With this snippet you get all buildings inside a polygon:

```
way(poly:"50.7 7.1 50.7 7.2 50.75 7.15")["building"];
(._;>;);
out body;
```